# How to Get Mods on a Hardmod (Modchip) Original Xbox?

Tags: mods, xbox, star-wars-kotor-2

I've gotten back into my Original Xbox a couple of days ago, and I've been wanting to mod one of my favorite games, SWKotOR 2 TSL (Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords), but haven't been able to. I've been searching the web all day and couldn't find anything that would work without buying something. I only have the console and controller, no other accessories besides a mother load of empty discs.

My main question is if there is any way to get the save files off the console with a disc? 
my Original Xbox has a ModChip making it hardmodded (not softmodded) and I want to know if there is any easy way to mod it. I also have a Xbox 360 that is just plain but if there's any free thing I could do to it I'm open for suggestions.

but again the main game I want to mod is TSL and the mod I want is KSE (TSL/Kotor Save Editor) but I can't get any saves off my console and I've tried downloading saves just to find out that I needed to buy something and I could even use KSE on it. please is there some way that I could get the saves off the console and onto my conputer?

Answer (score -3):

What I do is use the PC version, and FTP my saves to my computer. From there I put my saves into one of the folders containing my PC saves for Kotor.

When you open the save editor it then picks them up like it's on the computer.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a viable solution, can you expand on how to FTP the saves from xbox to PC?